# Set variable attribute for sort in mongoose

Tags: javascript, sorting, mongoose, server

```
router.get("/test/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var data = req.params.id;
    var sortAs= 0;

     if (data.localeCompare("0")) {
       sortAs= "price";
     } else {
       sortAs= "rating";
     }


    let addwises = await Addwise.find()
      .populate("reviews").sort({ sortAs: -1 })
      .exec();
    res.json({
      success: true,
      addwises: addwises,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Helo guys this is my code, but I have problem with sortAs in .sort() function. It does not detect that variable at all. What can I do to make it variable. If I put "price" or "rating" it's working, but otherwise it's not sorting corectly.

Comment: Hi, can you please share your Addwise mongoose schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ES6 syntax:

```
router.get("/test/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var data = req.params.id;
    var sortAs= 0;

     if (data.localeCompare("0")) {
       sortAs= "price";
     } else {
       sortAs= "rating";
     }


    let addwises = await Addwise.find()
      .populate("reviews").sort({ [sortAs]: -1 })
      .exec();
    res.json({
      success: true,
      addwises: addwises,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```

or pass an object

```
router.get("/test/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var data = req.params.id;
    var sortAs= {};

     if (data.localeCompare("0")) {
       sortAs["price"] =-1;
     } else {
       sortAs["rating"] = -1;
     }


    let addwises = await Addwise.find()
      .populate("reviews").sort(sortAs)
      .exec();
    res.json({
      success: true,
      addwises: addwises,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```